# Adding a shadow to an SVG on the one whole side

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to make some sort of drop-shadow that goes along this shape divider (a svg, a right triangle) and I am using the Tailwind CSS framework.

My problem is that on the far left edge, because the triangle is so small, there is no shadow. The result I hope is to have a shadow going all across,

Here is the HTML I currently have (Note, made using tailwind css):

```
<div class="relative h-20 mb-20">
    <svg class="w-full h-20 fill-current text-white shadow-bottom" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,100" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS for the shadow-bottom I am using:

```
.shadow-bottom {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
  filter: drop-shadow( 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));

}
```

Here is the result along with the other parts of the project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXbzK.png

As you can see, the left side does not have a shadow.

I tried messing around with adding another svg shifted a little bit and having a shadow effect, but I did not manage to get something that was better. I also tried looking around at adding a border only one that side of the svg and somehow adding some shadow effect, but I cannot seem to find a proper solution.

Thank you very much

Comment: I somewhat solved the problem by making it a trapezoid. The path is instead "0,0 0,20 100,100 100,0" which leaves the shadow on the whole side,  to the detriment of a milder angle.

Comment: If so then answer your question

Comment: @myckhel I didn't think it was the proper answer, due to it making a milder angle. JHeth has an approach that fits better the approach for me. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is using SVG filters to make your own drop shadow instead of using CSS, which will give you more control.

```
<div class="relative h-32 bg-blue-500">
<svg class="w-full h-20 block fill-current text-white overflow-visible" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="120%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="5" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="10" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="-20,-20 100,0 120,120" filter="url(#shadow)"/>
</svg>
```

In this approach you will also want to make the div wrapped around the SVG taller than the SVG itself to allow room for the shadow and extend the points of the polygon beyond the width of the SVG viewbox to prevent the shadow from getting 'thinner' less visible at the edges and last but not least make the SVG `overflow-visible`. Here is a Tailwind Play demo https://play.tailwindcss.com/PIjX1eV0lz

Comment: I never thought of using overflow-visible to solve this problem when I was testing out the SVG filters, that's the key, thank you very much.